# Using custom route and not allowing default route for specific action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I'm using MVC 4 and am customizing my routes.

I have a `Partners` action in my `About`. By default MVC matches the route `/About/Partners` to this action. I have set up a custom route so that `/Partners` maps to this action. My question is how do I make it so that `/About/Partners` no longer works for that action. I don't think I can alter the default route in the `route.config` file because it is being used by other actions.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting the new route **BEFORE** the default route

Comment: it is before the default route. The issue is that both routes work. I want only the /Partners to work, not the /About/Partners which would match the default route as it is /{controller}/{action}